# Cloning element based on dynamic value creating endless loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, onchange

I have a slider input field that gives a numeric value when slid. I would like to clone an object X times based on the slider value, however when I try to accomplish this it creates an endless loop. Is there anyway to get the number of cloned elements to match the slider value when it changes? Here is the code I was using.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(window).load(function() {

$('input#fieldname3_1').change(function() {

var e = $('#student-icons.icon > span');
var n = $('#fieldname9_1').val();

$('#student-icons.icon').html(
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      e.clone().insertAfter(e);
});
}).change()
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following setup:

HTML:

```
<input type="range" id='fieldname3_1' style='width: 200px'>

<div id='student-icons' class='icon'></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
        $('input#fieldname3_1').change(function() {
            var n = $(this).val();

            // reset the element
            $('#student-icons.icon').html('');
            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                // The html of what you want to clone goes here
                $('#student-icons.icon').append("<div id='hello'>"+i+"</div>")
            }
        });
});
```

I also recommend using the `oninput` event if browser support is not an issue (IE 9 and up only):

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
        $('input#fieldname3_1')[0].oninput = function() {
            var n = $(this).val();

            $('#student-icons.icon').html('');
            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                $('#student-icons.icon').append("<div id='hello'>"+i+"</div>")
            }
        };
});
```

This will allow the event to fire as soon as the input is changed rather than wait on the keydown.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uny7qevg/1)
[JsFiddle w/ onInput](https://jsfiddle.net/uny7qevg/2/)